# Show crystal report using DataSet object using Access 2003 Database

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, dataset, ms-access-2003

Private Sub frmReportExpenses_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

```
    Dim objDatasetExpence As New dSetExpences   // dataset object named as dSetExpences
    Dim objRptExpence As New rptExpences       // Crystal report object
    Dim MyCommand As New OleDbCommand()
    Dim MyConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim myDA As New OleDbDataAdapter()

    Try
        Dim connstring As String = "D:\HMSProjects\SMS\SMS\bin\Debug\"
        MyConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + connstring + "msautoconfig.mdb;")
        MyConnection.Open()
        MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection

        MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM expences"
        MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        myDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand

        myDA.Fill(objDatasetExpence, "expences")
        objRptExpence.SetDataSource(objDatasetExpence)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRptExpence
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End Sub
```

End Class

whats wrong in above code its not working. i want to show crystal report using Access 2003 Database pragmatically. blank report is added in project and trying to fill it DataSet object, any suggestion or correction in above code. its a windows form application

Comment: Can you explain what "Dim objRptExpence As New rptExpences" is doing? Is the report loading at all? For example, does text in the page header appear?